# how to add arabic support for android SDK Emulator (2.3)

Tags: android, android-emulator, arabic, android-sdk-2.3

How can i add arabic language support in Emulator of android SDK ? it`s displayed word`s as separated  like this :

> س ل ا م

how can slove this problam ?

Answer (score 0):

Try out what is in this [link](http://mdictionary.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/connected-arabic-characters-for-android-apps/) ,  there is a class or 2 by adding them to ur project u will be able to get the arabic characters connected on the emulator.